# The couple holding hand with intertwine finger

Tags: grammaticality

The couple holding hand with intertwine finger.
The couple intertwine their hand.

Intertwine hand or finger. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding hands with *fingers intertwined* or *interlaced*